# PHP .htaccess file Configuration

Tags: .htaccess

My URL

```
myurl.co.kr
```

Redirected URL

```
myurl.co.kr/#page1
```

I have tried this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/#page1
```

However, this caused "too many redirections" on chrome.

How should I change the .htaccess file so that it redirects with the "/#page1" added on the URL?

Comment: Do you have any other rules apart from these in your .htaccess file?

Comment: The fragment portion of the URL is not send to the server. So you have absolutely no way of telling there, whether the URL on the client already contains `#page1` or not. You need to do this using a client side technique (JavaScript, or meta refresh.)

Comment: No, I do not have any other rules but these top two lines.

PHP_FLAG register_globals ON
PHP_VALUE mysql.default_charset UTF8

Comment: @KangYul, Your `RewriteCond`  right side condition is empty, so you need to put a condition there may be try changing it to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$` once and give it a shot?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks for the suggestion. I've found a better way for the redirection by using a client side technique (Javascript).

Comment: @KangYul, Sure, good to hear. You can add it that solution in **answer** section in this question(don't update your question answer section is different) so that future users can be benefited from your answer, cheers.